# How do aborted css3 transitions work with regards to reversal timing?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Lets consider the following example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  transition: width 4s linear;
}

div:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover out after 1 second</div>
```

Now when I hover the width changes from 100px to 500px in 4 seconds. When the width becomes 500px, now if I mouseout of the div the width will change back to 100px in 4 seconds again. So far so good.

Instead lets start it again. The width is 100px, I hover in and when width becomes 200px I mouseout. Now from 200px to 100px it takes 1 second not 4 seconds. Why is this? Why don't the transition takes 4 second to go from 200px to 100px now? Plz mention the section of w3c draft which explains this behavior. And also please elaborate over that as the docs are somewhat rigorous for me.

**Edit:** Proof of cases where it takes 4 second for 100px.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  div.className = "";
  div.className = "first";
  setTimeout(function(){
    div.className = "second";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  transition: width 4s linear;
}

div.first {
  width: 500px;
}
div.second {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>First time takes 4s for 400px then 4s for 100px</div>
<button id="btn">start and reset</button>
```

Comment: If 500px to 100px takes 4 seconds why would you expect 200px to 100px take 4 seconds. Your expectations seem incorrect.

Comment: @Fran I have added example where it takes 4 seconds for 400px but then again 4 seconds for 100px.

Comment: The, in this case, 4 seconds is not about distance, its the duration it should take to change value _a_ to _b_.

Comment: @LGSon Yes it takes 4 seconds from a(100px) to b(400px). But I thought it should 4 seconds again for from a(200px) to b(100px). Now I understand as per w3c rule if in midway of transition we set b=a then it just reverses to a and takes only that much time it used previously, not 4seconds.

Comment: Yes, the duration is defined for the transition to reach its end, if aborted, it will recalculate its reverse from the point it got aborted, which simply means it will take the same amount of time to reverse as it took to the position where it got aborted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#reversing describes this expectation:

> If the outgoing and incoming transitions are executed using their
>   specified durations and timing functions, the resulting effect can be
>   distractingly asymmetric because the second transition takes the full
>   specified time to move a shortened distance. Instead, the expected
>   behavior is that the second transition is shorter.

They then go on to more precisely define how the browser should meet this expectation.

The key is that you may have been expecting something asymmetric, but, as the quote above shows, they working group considers this to be distracting, so the spec goes to lengths to instead make symmetrical effects.  The *effect* of something, visually, has to do with its speed, so the calculations they give work out such that the speed of the transition appears the same no matter the direction in which it's running.  You were expecting the *time* to be equal, but that would then make the *speed* different in an aborted transition, making for an asymmetric effect.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. As I understand it, it means if a transtion go from A to C but before it reaches C(lets say its at B) if we change the value back to A then from B to A it will not take 4seconds. On the other hand if when it was at B we change the final value Z then from B to Z it will still take 4 seconds.

Comment: @Kev Could you add some explanation too.

Comment: @user31782 added as requested.  Hopefully that clarifies things.

Answer (score 2):

The transition takes 4 seconds to go from 100px to 500px, now if you're removing hover state at 200px it will take 1/4 of the time because (200px - 100px)/400px is 1/4.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transitions)

Answer (score 0):

you specified that the transition from 100px to 500px will take 4s. that's 1s/100px which means 200px to 100px will take 1s.

Comment: I have added example where it takes 4s for 400px first but thereafter it takes 4s for 100px.

Comment: you were interrupting the animation before

Comment: The same holds true event if I interrupt the animation. If you wish I can add another example.

Answer (score 0):

there are differences in logic between the 2 examples

**your first example**

here you INTERRUPT the 4s second transition

you have a div of `100px` width and you 'say' that when hovering, in 4s , the div to become `500px` width

let's say you have `meters` instead of `px` . and you have to drive `400m` ( from 100 to 500 )  in 4s at constant speed. so you drive `400m / 4s` = 100m per second

so if you stop ( interrupt ) after `100m` ( mouseout at 200px width ), you would've been driving for just `1second` and if you turn back , it will take you `1second` to get back from where you started

that's why it takes only 1 second to return from `200px` to `100px`

**your second example**

here is NOT the same as in the first one BECAUSE :

here you DO NOT INTERRUPT but instead
you are saying : ' i want to change the divs width from 100px to 500px in 4 seconds, then change it from 500px to 400px also in 4s '

that's why it takes 4s to go 100px in your second example

let me know if you understood what i wanted to say :) cheers